# Android Firebase: Set Value not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add an test value to Firebase Database by following code:

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("shop").child("Users");
                   
 usersRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue("test");
```

And the database looks like this:

[image]

But unfortunately, it's not working. Where am i wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your user uid.

Comment: Did you authenticate the user?

Comment: Debug the value of user.getUid() . If its ok then add a completion listener to check the error.

Comment: @NoumanCh It's normal

Comment: @ADM How can i add completion listener?

Comment: @PeterHaddad i am trying to develop the register. After registing, i will add the info of users to the database and it's not working. The authentication is ok

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback

Comment: I think you are adding the value to NOT existed UID  node .. you need to save the UID to firebase database first

Comment: @Mohammad the  node exists :(

Comment: may be you need to change database rules to true if you haven't authenticated the user yet

Answer (score 2):

Go to the console of firebase on firebase.google.com
Then click on rules and then set rules like this 
you can do this easily

```
".read": "auth!=null",
".write": "auth!=null"
```

and then click publish then try again it will work 100% sure.

make sure your code is also correct in your android studio.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and I got the answer hope it's not too late for others.....

1. After Creating Realtime database go to Project Settings in firebase dashboard -> Project Overview -> Gear Icon -> Project Settings and scroll down and check google-services.json file and download it again and replace with same place in android studio -> select project view -> in app folder (you know the drill) .... and clean - rebuild app again...... it worked for me after hours of trying .....
2. in short just redownload and replace google-services.json again and clean - rebuild project....

Comment: thanks a lot; it was so simple yet wasted so much time; thanks for your answer here else I would have wasted so many more hours on this