# push().setValue() function do nothing when I try to insert data to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert to my Realtime Database on Firebase user data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
DatabaseReference reference;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");

}


public void onClick(View view) {
    String phone = "+00000000", firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith", email = "johnsmith@gmail.com";
    User user = new User(phone,firstName,lastName,email);
    reference.push().setValue(user);
}
```

I tried this code but when I click on the button nothing happen beside the Toast..

Database Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I don't get any error when I click the button.

[image: database img]

I'm trying to create database of users every user have phone, first name, last name, email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Firebase: Set Value not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706889/android-firebase-set-value-not-working)

Comment: I changed the rules but it's still not working

Comment: Your `".write": "auth!=null"` rule only allows writes by an authenticated user. Since your code doesn't seem to sign in to Firebase Authentication, it seems correct that the write gets rejected.

Comment: Have you tried to set the value to "true", for testing purposes? Does it work that way?

Comment: I changed the rule cause the person above told me should I change it back?

Comment: I just changed it back to {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
  ".write": "true"
  }
} 

it doesn't work this way too..

Comment: What are you expecting this `User user = new User(b,b,b,b);` to be? And then what are you expecting this `reference.push().setValue(user)` do to? Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: I'm trying to create database of users every user have phone, first name, last name, email. (check the edit)

Comment: I could really use some help :I

Comment: I would suggest using the exact code from the getting started guide [Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data) and see what happens.